# How to add spell check for multi-line textarea

Tags: html, textarea

I am new to coding and
have code that looks like this

```
<div class="txtarea">
  <div>
    <textarea rows=22 placeholder="Code Goes Here" class="text" id="input" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea rows=22 readonly id="output" class="out"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add a spellcheck functionality to the textarea that highlights the spelling errors with custom words in the editable text area

Can someone help please...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi kevin, lemme get this straight, you want the textarea to be multiline. Am i right?

Comment: Yeah. That's a very important part.

Comment: Kevin I think the problem is in your CSS or JS since the HTML is working fine by itself. Have a look https://codepen.io/Joel-N-Sorceror/pen/xxRymXe

Comment: There is no problem, I just need to add a custom spell checker.